# Python: hide warning for "TIFFSetField"

Tags: python, suppress-warnings

I'm working with some TIFF files

The script will output "TIFFSetField: tempfile.tif: Unknown pseudo-tag 65538."

Is it possible to ignore/hide this?

Things I have tried running with:

```
-W ignore
```

and including this:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: can you post more of your script?

Comment: It should be safe to ignore this, but appears to be caused by your TIFF file using an old JPEG compression technique deprecated 23 years ago. See more info [here](https://github.com/openpreserve/format-corpus/tree/master/tiff-examples/old-style-jpeg-compression)

Comment: I presume you're using pillow, this is something they seem to have a patch in the works for so you might just need to make sure you're using latest version: 

patch: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/3417  

reported: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3413

Comment: This is not a Python warning, it is emitted by the tiff decoding library PIL uses and you see it because there is a bug in PIL / Pillow. It has been fixed and will be part of the release coming out in January. See https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3413. You can't silence this from Python, you have to patch Pillow and re-compile or wait for the new release.

Answer (score 0):

How about redirecting stderr to stdin, and culling it out with grep?

```
python tiff.py 2>&1 | grep -v pseudo-tag
```

Comment: This isn't a helpful solution for ipynb cells. Could you give an alternative for ipynb?